# Use dconf (or comparable) to set configs for another user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity, dbus

On Ubuntu Desktop 13.10, I have a setup script which runs as root. It essentially configures the computer as necessary, but I need to set some things with `dconf`. The script runs in a Terminal window under a regular user with `sudo`. I need to run the command `dconf write /com/canonical/unity/launcher/favorites "['unity://expo-icon', <...>']"`. (It is run with a variety of different settings.)

I have tested the commands as the login user, and they work just fine. However, when I am logged in as root, I cannot do `sudo -u bitc dconf write <...>`; I get errors like `error: Could not connect: Connection refused` or `unable to create directory '/root/.cache/conf'`.

The script must be run as root because of some other tasks it performs, but it appears that `dconf` must be run under the specific login session, not just the user, to configure it. I would rather not have a separate script for `dconf`, but that is possible. Is there a way to attach to the login session (or some other way to set the `dconf` keys for that user)?

(The script is written in javascript with node.js.)

Comment: Doesn't dconf need an X session owned by the user in question to run?

Answer (score 3):

Is it sufficient to do this?

```
sudo -u bitc HOME=/home/bitc dconf write <...>
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I was trying to do something similar. I have a script that connects via SSH and runs as root. I want it to change some settings for a user. This seems to work for me:

```
sudo -u vagrant HOME=/home/vagrant dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.general use-system-keyboard-layout true
```

I think that's potentially bad because it's spawning a new dbus-daemon for the duration of the this session, but without the dbus-launch I got dbus errors. Perhaps these are specific to gsettings, but I want to mention it in case it helps.

Comment: Adding the HOME definition saved my day, thanks :) (I'm using dconf from puppet to configure multiple users)

Answer (score 0):

I have a POST-Install script that sets my gsetting. Because I run the script as sudo the EUID is 0, there fore I have to find the $RUID (Real User ID).

here is my approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Get the Real Username
RUID=$(who | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}')

# Translate Real Username to Real User ID
RUSER_UID=$(id -u ${RUID})

# Set gsettings for the Real User
sudo -u ${RUID} DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/${RUSER_UID}/bus" gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date false

exit
```

Comment: `sudo -u` also works with username.